# Find a CFG for all the binary strings in which the characters in $i$ and $i + 2$ positions are same, and the length of the string is at least 2.

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I have homework which is about CFGs, their simplification, and their normalized forms. I have also seen some examples on the internet, but unfortunately, I could not solve the below question.

> All the binary numbers, in which the $i$th character is equal to the
> character which is located in $i + 2$ th position, and the length of
> these strings is at least $2$.

My problem is with positions, and how to show them using our grammar.
My idea was to have $S$ as our initial state, and then have a production like this:

### $S\Rightarrow A|B$

And then $A$ be for all the strings which start by $0$, and $B$ be for all the strings which start by $1$.
But I will be really grateful for your help.

Comment: Hii, welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and provide context. Show us your working, on what step you got stuck and need help, your thoughts about the problem etc. Have a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) text to know how to ask a good question here.

Comment: @Yooo, I have added some more lines, I think it is not enough, but I am just a beginner in this field. Thanks.

Comment: Is $i$ fixed? Meaning, for instance, we want strings where the characters at positions 1 and 3 are the same? Or is $i$ universally quantified, where for a string $\omega$, we want $\omega_{1} = \omega_{3} = \omega_{5} = \cdots$ and $\omega_{2} = \omega_{4} = \omega_{6} = \cdots$?

Comment: @ml0105, no, $i$ is not fixed.

Comment: Here is a hint then: start by designing a grammar where the even characters are $0$ and the odd characters are $1$.

Comment: @ml0105, I think we also need a grammar when the even positions are filled with $1$ and the odd positions are filled with $0$. And then union these two grammars. Am I right?

Comment: @AylinNaebzadeh Yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can divide this language into 4 groups, and then use a union between them.
The first 2 bits can be 00, 01, 10, or 11.
So we need 4 states besides the initial state.

$S \Rightarrow 00A|01B|10C|11D$

And then we add 4 productions:

$A \Rightarrow 0A|ɛ$

$B \Rightarrow 01B|0|ɛ$

$C \Rightarrow 10C|1|ɛ$

$D \Rightarrow 1D|ɛ$

Answer (score 0):

These are strings like 01, 010, 0101, 01010, .. and 10, 101, ... .

Consider a grammar like S-> abS | ab, which produces even length strings of the form ab, abab, ababab, ... . Consider how you'd modify the grammar to (1) produce odd length strings, (2) start with b instead.

For example, S-> abA. A-> e|a|abA is a grammar that can produce odd length strings.

Comment: Why do you rewrite the grammar base on its length, to be odd or even? But can I add a new production rule like $X \Rightarrow babX | ba$, and then use union like $Y \Rightarrow S|X$?

Comment: You don't have to. The idea is to start with a grammar that almost works, then modify it so that it works better.  The first grammar I proposed produces alternating strings, but they're all even. So you have to fix it by making them odd too.

Comment: Actually, I can not understand how to modify it to work for both odd and even lengths, and also with lengths more than 2.